# How to configure the annotaion value with configuration file like .properties/.xml/.yml in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

A code snippet for a specific case

```java
@Configuration
@NewEnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 900)
@Import({RedisConfiguration.class})
```

Here is a annotation value: `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 900`

```java
@NewEnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 900)
```

I want to configure it like

`@NewEnableRedisHttpSession("${maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds}")`

some configuration file will give the value
`maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 900`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```java
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = intervalInSeconds)
```

more specific for your need

```java
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 900)
```

default value is `1800` .

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.html section `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds` .

**Supplement based on comment.** Do like this, in case you want get value from `application.properties`

```
spring.session.timeout=9000
```

```java
@Value("${spring.session.timeout}")
private Integer maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds;
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440818/3728901

Comment: Thanks for you reply!  
Does`@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = intervalInSeconds)` means I can set intervalInSeconds in configuration file ? 
I know I can give a value to `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds`, but what I need is to set the value in **configuration file**.

Comment: Yes, you can set value in `application.properties` or another `*.properties` file. See more in my edited answer.

Comment: Cool, I will have a try.

Comment: You can set key as another string, for example `spring.session.timeoutFooBar=900` , `spring.session.timeoutFooBarZuu=1900` ; then change accordingly at `@Value("${spring.session.timeoutFooBarZuu}")`

Comment: Seems work, you save my days！Thanks